# Attribute routing not picking up index action in routedata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following MVC Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("our-brochure")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class OurBrochureController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Which works fine - if I go to `http://localhost/our-brochure` it goes to the index page and loads it as expected

However, for my navigation, I have a `NavModel` that works out the current controller and action using the following code:

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

This gives me the correct controller name of "OurBrochure" but `routeData.Values["action"]` is null.

Is this the expected behaviour as I would think that I would get "Index" as the action in the route data.  If this is the expected behaviour, how do you get the current action name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem, instead of getting the `RouteData` using the above methods, you can get it directly from the Current Context:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```